Cannot determine a GraphQL output type for the "userRoles". Make sure your class is decorated with an appropriate decorator. nest js
I have written my code as shown below:
import { Field, ObjectType } from '@nestjs/graphql';

@ObjectType()
export class Role {
  @Field()
  name: string;
}

export class UserRoles {
  role: Role
}

@ObjectType()
export class User extends BaseEntity {
  @Field()
  @Field()
  name: string;

  @Field()
  email: string;

  @Field()
  isValid: boolean;

  @HideField()
  password: string;

  @Field(() => [UserRoles])
  userRoles: UserRoles[];


  @Field({ nullable: true })
  isAdmin?: boolean;

  @Field()
  confirm: boolean;
}

@ObjectType()
export class UserPaginated extends Paginated(User) { }

When I attempt to query the data, I get the following error message:
Error: Cannot determine a GraphQL output type for the "userRoles". Make sure your class is decorated with an appropriate decorator.
    at OutputTypeFactory.create (\node_modules\@nestjs\graphql\dist\schema-builder\factories\output-type.factory.js:19:23)

I have searched for different solutions online but none of them is working.
Can anyone help?
